# Ansible best practice - When to use "ini_file" module instead of "copy"

Tags: ansible

I struggle to find best practices or conventions making it easier to maintain and for others to read my Ansible playbooks/roles. Let's say I'm creating an ini-file:

```
[drinks]
fav=lemonade
```

There are multiple ways to do this in Ansible, I'll mention two:

1. Use `ini_file` module
2. Copy a file with the same content using the `copy` module

Which method is preferable?

Thanks.

Comment: Your list of methods is quite restrictive (e.g. I could add `template`, copy using the `content` attribute, `lineinfile`, `blockinfile`....). And the best method is... the one fat fits to your exact requirements. In other words, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: As I mentioned, there are multiple ways to solve this, I tried to group them saying "infile-modules", meaning lineINFILE, blockINFILE, but I ended up with ini_file... haha.

Comment: @Zeitounator: The question covers [*software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The requirement is exact and the question is answerable.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I don't think it was exactly answerable without further input from OP. The fact that your own answer starts with a question and lists several solutions depending on the exact situation tends to prove my point. Meanwhile, your answer is still lean and concise, well done (as usual :))

Comment: Right. <offtopic> In most cases, one can ask better questions once some answers are available. You know that [questions are more important than answers](http://www.learning-knowledge.com/criticism.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the source of the data. Where does the data come from?

- If a file is available from whatever source use the [*copy*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#ansible-builtin-copy-copy-files-to-remote-locations) module.
- If you want to add the section to an existing file use the [*ini_file*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html#community-general-ini-file-tweak-settings-in-ini-files) module.
- If data is structured use the [*template*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#ansible-builtin-template-template-a-file-out-to-a-remote-server) module. For example,

```yaml
my_ini_data:
  drinks:
    - key: fav
      val: lemonade
```

```
shell> cat conf.ini.j2
{% for section in my_ini_data.items() %}
[{{ section.0 }}]
{% for item in section.1 %}
{{ item.key }}={{ item.val }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

```yaml
    - template:
        src: conf.ini.j2
        dest: conf.ini
```

gives

```ini
shell> cat conf.ini
[drinks]
fav=lemonade
```

In addition to this, it's a good idea to take a look at the authors of the module. [*template*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#authors) and [*copy*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#authors) are maintained by Ansible Core Team. If you have problems take a look at the [open issues](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues) first.

Comment: `
my_ini_data:
  drinks:
     - key: fav
       val: lemonade
     - key: least
       val: cola
   food:
      - key: fav
        val: pizza
`

So I should use template in this case is what you're saying.

Comment: I've added an example of *template*.

Comment: I see that I had an extra key "between" `my_ini_data` and `drinks`, resulting in one extra for-loop, but I see your point through your example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use it like so:

vault has list of users (lets say mysql db):

```
# Ansible vault: vault.yml

mysql:
  ini_fields:
    - username
    - password
    - database
    - host
 
  users: 
    ansible:
      hostname: localhost
      username: ansibleuser
      password: somepass
      database: myorgdb
      privileges: "INSERT,UPDATE,SELECT,DELETE,DROP,CREATE"

    user2:
      ...
  
    user3:
      ...
```

Then I create the playbook task with a combination of both `ini_fields` and the `users` dicts ( since not all information inside users :

```
- name: Reading secrets
  include_vars:
    file: path/to/secrets/vault.yml
    name: secrets
  tags:
    - always

- name: Dropping secrets to INI files
  ini_file:
     path: "/my/secrets/dir/mysql.ini"
     section: "{{ item.0 }}"    # (main loop) 
     option: "{{ item.1 }}"     # (inner loop) 
     value : "{{ secrets.mysql.users[item.0][item.1] }}"  
     mode  : 0640
   no_log: True
   with_nested:
     - "{{ secrets.mysql.users }}"
     - "{{ secrets.mysql.ini_fields }}"
   tags:
     - secrets
```

Basically the loop is going something like this:

```
# first main loop: 
# item.0    item.1
['ansible', 'username']
['ansible', 'password']
['ansible', 'database']
['ansible', 'host']

# 2nd loop:
# item.0  item.1
['user2', 'username']
['user2', 'password']
['user2', 'database']
['user2', 'host']
```